# How to pass Hashmap into spring data jpa method and use that in update statement?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I would like to update multiple rows of a table using Case clause in the update query.

I have an `Map<String, String>` which contains values of 2 columns. Key acts as the identifier of the row and the value in the map is the value of the column I want to update.

How can I do this in a spring data JPA `@Query`?

I would like to achieve something like

```
@Modifying

@Query("update RequestDetail rd set value = VALUE(:statusDetails) where name='Status' and RequestUuid=KEY(:statusDetails)")
void updateBulkStatus(Map<String, String> statusDetails);
```

But this is giving the exception - `antlr.SemanticException: node did not reference a map`.

Goal is to avoid multiple update queries to DB.

What better ways we have to update multiple rows with multiple values to a single column.

Comment: You can use createNativeQuery(), which will return a List of type Object[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to execute something like:

```
Update RequestDetail rd set rd.value = CASE WHEN (rd.name = :name1) THEN :value1 WHEN (rd.name = :name2) THEN :value2 WHEN (rd.name = :name3) THEN :value3 END
```

But you will not necessarily know how many items will be in the map, so you will need to generate your query text, like

```
String sql = "Update RequestDetail rd set CASE ";
int index = 1;
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : statusDetails.entrySet()) {
    sql += " WHEN (rd.name = :name" + index + ") THEN :value" + (index++) + " ";
}
sql += " END";
```

You will also need to pass the parameters to your query.